# How to make an easily embeddable React component that displays any other component's state when used as its child?

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to make a React component that, when inserted inside any other component, will display its state in a DIV floated to the right of the screen. Let name it `StateExplorer`.

Because many `StateExplorers` can be used on the same page, the DIVs will stack with the same `z-index`.

The challenge here is to make `StateExplorer` easily non-verbosely embeddable, like this:

```
<SomeComponent>
    <StateExplorer/>
    ....
</SomeComponent>
```

The particular issue here is: how do I hook on componentWillUpdate() so that the StateExplorer always displays up-to-date state? I could use a mixin, but that throws 2 problems:

1. `componentWillUpdate()` can be implemented already in the parent component
2. adding a mixing adds more verbosity; the ideal case is to just add `StateExplorer` and nothing more.

P.S. I know about React Debug Tools, but it's not so convenient in some cases and adds extra steps before you can see state of a single component.

Comment: How does a mixin add more verbosity? Neither option is zero touch if you want to stick to something that doesn't rely on internals of React. In fact the mixin would have better access to the component lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need is a **Higher-order component**. 
Here is a good article about it: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750